# Spring Boot 3.0.0 + Spring Cloud 2021.0.5 No Feign Client for loadBalancing defined. Did you forget to include spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am using Spring Boot 3.0.0 , Spring Cloud 2021.0.5 . I have `BillingServiceApplication.java`

```java
package org.sid.billingservice;

import org.sid.billingservice.entities.Bill;
import org.sid.billingservice.entities.ProductItem;
import org.sid.billingservice.model.Customer;
import org.sid.billingservice.model.Product;
import org.sid.billingservice.repository.BillRepository;
import org.sid.billingservice.repository.ProductItemRepository;
import org.sid.billingservice.services.CustomerRestClient;
import org.sid.billingservice.services.ProductRestClient;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ImportAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
@ImportAutoConfiguration({FeignAutoConfiguration.class})
public class BillingServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BillingServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner start(BillRepository billRepository, ProductItemRepository productItemRepository, CustomerRestClient customerRestClient, ProductRestClient productRestClient) {
        return args -> {
            Collection<Product> products = productRestClient.allProducts().getContent();
            Long customerId = 1L;
            Customer customer = customerRestClient.findCustomerById(customerId);
            if (customer == null) throw new RuntimeException("Customer not found");
            Bill bill = new Bill();
            bill.setBillDate(new Date());
            bill.setCustomerId(customerId);
            Bill savedBill = billRepository.save(bill);
            products.forEach(product -> {
                ProductItem productItem = new ProductItem();
                productItem.setBill(savedBill);
                productItem.setProductId(product.getId());
                productItem.setQuantity(1 + new Random().nextInt(10));
                productItem.setPrice(product.getPrice());
                productItem.setDiscount(Math.random());
                productItemRepository.save(productItem);
            });
        };
    }

}
```

my error

```
No Feign Client for loadBalancing defined. Did you forget to include spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer?
```

Log error full https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/348aa7b096cde63a7129ad0f009c7507

How to fix it?

Comment: My full source code of microservices system https://github.com/donhuvy/micro-service-usecase

Comment: Spring Cloud is tied to certain versions of Spring Boot. Your version isn't compatible afaik. You need 2022.0.x not 2021.0.x which is for Spring Boot 2.6/2.7.

Comment: `2022.x` is the one compatible with Boot `3.0.0`. However, it's not GA yet. The release is planned for mid-December; if you're using Spring Cloud in your apps, we suggest you wait till then with doing the switch to Boot 3.

Answer (score 1):

please share your pom.xml. It looks like you don't have spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer dependency in your project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I did this, but not success.

Comment: do you have spring.cloud.loadbalancer.enabled=true in your application.yml

Comment: Yes. It did not work.

Comment: I added this to pom.xml and worked for me also I didn't add this spring.cloud.loadbalancer.enabled=true

Answer (score 1):

That could mean you forgot to define the `url` property of your `@FeignClient` or the property is empty. Check your class code and application properties.

```
    @FeignClient(name = "myfeignclient", url = "${my.url}")
    public interface TestFeignClient {
        @GetMapping(value = "/test")
        public Map<String, String> test();
    }
```

There is an issue about this confusing error message:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/517

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `path` with `url` in feign client class along with `@ImportAutoConfiguration({FeignAutoConfiguration.class})` in main class worked for me.